# BigQuery: Search for all elements matching in subquery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Given data: table1

```
        column 1 column 2 column 3 
Row1    k1       k2       k3
Row2    k1       k4       k3
Row3    k1       k2       k3
```

I want to select all rows which is matching keys in rows returned in subquery.

```
select *
from tabl1
where Exists(select * 
             from table1
             where column2 = k2)
```

Should return rows with (k1       k2       k3). Is this correct approach? Why would we use `Exists()` rather than `In()` subquery expression?

**Note: This question is simple version where in real life, I am matching against many rows (TBs) returned by subquery against many rows (TBs) returned by outer query**

Comment: This is a simple example to simplify the problem, in reality I have many rows (TBs) and columns where I need to match against subquery.

Comment: Its not yet clear why you need the subquery with the example.  Typically IN/EXISTS is used for semijoin situations, but this appears to be a simple filtration of a table.  Can you elaborate?

Comment: Unfortunately, your example is simplified up to the point when it makes no sense and there is no way to reverse-engineer the logic. Please edit your question with more details of what exactly you are trying to achieve and supply some meaningful example of input and output - so some of us will be able to help you

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.